# Clear Value of a TextBox

Tags: excel, vba

I've got an excel UserForm with two TextBox and a Button. How can I delete the value of the TextBox without using `TextBox1.Value = ""` or `TextBox1.Text = ""` ?

I can't use these two operations because then the instruction: `TextBox2.Value = TextBox1.value*2`
give me back an error. (The error is Runtime error 13)

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea why do you get that error msg? please, share more info with us in order to help you.

Comment: In that case, you can set TextBox1.Text = 0

Comment: I can't use `TextBox1.Text = 0` because I want to have the TextBox field *blank*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the problem a different way.  If box1 is empty then why would you want to multiply it by 2?  In this case you should error check the value of box1 before you multiply it by box2.  The code below checks if Textbox1 is a number and is not empty before multiplying it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Error check: does textbox1 have a number and is not null
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) And TextBox1.Value <> vbNullString Then
        TextBox2.Value = TextBox1.Value * 2
    Else
        TextBox2.Value = "Box1 is empty or invalid"
    End If
End Sub
```

Valid Number:

[image]

Invalid or empty:

[image]

Comment: Ok, this is a good alternative, but now my problem is another... 
I would need the code for "clean" the textbox and reset it as *blank* because in my form I use the button for *reinitialize* the Form..

Comment: For that I would add a new button called 'clear form' and then set each textbox that you want cleared like this `TextBox1.Value = ""`.  If you want all text boxes cleared then you can run a loop.

Comment: or a simple `Unload me`, followed by `UserForm1.show`. Not very beautifull, but practical, and works even if later you decide to add new controls to the form.